# Consider the set $S$ of all symmetric matrices of a given size $n$ with entries lying in $\{0,1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $S$ of all symmetric matrices of a given size $n$ with entries lying in $\{0,1\}$  such that all diagonal entries of matrices in $S$ are zeros. Now does there exists an invertible matrix $A$ in $S$ such that $A$ is permutation similar to its inverse $A^{-1}$ and entries of $A^{-1}$ also lies in $\{0,1\}$

definition of permutation similar matrices can be found here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity#:~:text=In%20the%20definition%20of%20similarity,equivalent%20to%20some%20diagonal%20matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity#:%7E:text=In%20the%20definition%20of%20similarity,equivalent%20to%20some%20diagonal%20matrix).

I have found one such matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Does there exists other such types of matrices, at least one example

Comment: Your $A$ is easily generalized to any even $n$. So there's that.

Comment: Doesn't every permutation matrix with no fixed elements satisfy these conditions?  (And that should fully characterize these matrices.)

Comment: thank you..does there exists other matrices satisfying this condition which are not permutation matrices?

Comment: @mjqxxxx: The question requires matrices in $S$ to be _symmetric_, so $A$ can't be the matrix of a permutation that has any cycle of length $\ne 2$.

Comment: @Troposphere I missed the symmetric constraint... so I think you are right.